# Drawing a square using Javascript, WebGL and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, webgl

Hi I am following Edward Angel's Introduction to Interactive 3D Graphics. I want to make a recursive maze but first I need to be able to do a basic square. I modeled this script on the book script for a sierpinski gasket. I have been hours at this and just cant see what I am doing wrong. HTML page will only display one line. Ive tried different types of vertex joiner like LINES LINE_LOOP POLYGON but I cant seem to get it to work. Please help me out I feel like Im going crazy.
Here is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<title>Maze Sierpinski Gasket</title>


<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;


void
main()
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script>
//goal: try and draw just a square.

var canvas;
var gl;

var points = [];



window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

   //enter new script 

var vertices = [
  vec2(-1.0,-1.0),
  vec2(-1.0,1.0),
  vec2(1.0,1.0),
  vec2(1.0,-1.0)
];

square(vertices[0],vertices[1],vertices[2],vertices[3]);

//
    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    render();
};

function square(a,b,c,d)
{
points.push(a);
points.push(b);
points.push(c);
points.push(d);
}


function render(){
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, points.length);
}

</script>
</head>   

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive spotted the lack of a ; after function square(a,b,c,d)
{
points.push(a);
points.push(b);
points.push(c);
points.push(d);
}

Comment: but it still doesnt work

Comment: Just thought I'd pass on [these articles](http://webglfundamentals.org).

Answer (score 1):

2 issues

1. Assuming a standard implementation of `flatten` it returns a JavaScript native array but `gl.bufferData` requires a typed array. So I changed it to

   ```
   gl.bufferData(..., new Float32Array(flatten(...)), ...
   ```
2. `gl.LINES` draws every pair of points. You're only passing in 4 points which means 2 lines. You won't get a square with that. You could use `gl.LINE_LOOP` to connect all 4 points and the last to the first as well.

Also, when I ran your code I got errors in the JavaScript console which helped me find the issues. You should always check the JavaScript console for errors and warnings.

```js
//goal: try and draw just a square.

var canvas;
var gl;

var points = [];

function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

   //enter new script 

var vertices = [
  vec2(-1.0,-1.0),
  vec2(-1.0,1.0),
  vec2(1.0,1.0),
  vec2(1.0,-1.0)
];

square(vertices[0],vertices[1],vertices[2],vertices[3]);

//
    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(flatten(points)), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    render();
};

function square(a,b,c,d)
{
points.push(a);
points.push(b);
points.push(c);
points.push(d);
}


function render(){
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, points.length);
}

// ---------------[ missing functions ] ---------

var WebGLUtils = {
  setupWebGL: function(canvas) {
    return canvas.getContext("webgl");
  },
};

function initShaders(gl, vs, fs) {
  return twgl.createProgramFromScripts(gl, [vs, fs]);
}

function vec2(x, y) {
  return [x, y];
}

function flatten(arrayOfArrays) {
  var flattened =  arrayOfArrays.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }, []);
  return flattened;
}
  
init();
```

```html
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;


void
main()
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
```

Comment: I'll definitely have a look over this but when I run code snippet it still doesn't produce a square. Thought?

Comment: Did you scroll? What did you see? [This is what I see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSjXt3pLuAg)

Comment: For the record, I'm just seeing the top and right lines on chrome, linux. I'm assuming that the lines are clipped due to the coordinates lying directly on the edge, using `.99` instead of `1` or a `lineWidth` > 1 renders correctly.

Comment: That's actually strange, I thought OpenGL ES had some pretty precise definitions of what's supposed to happen but yea, 1.0 is right on the edge so who knows.